# Foursquare current score of a user

Tags: foursquare

I was skimming through the 4sq API documentation but couldn't find any info about the current score of the user in any of the Json responses.

Anyone saw it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is end point for the leader board, [Leader Board Stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html#req=users/leaderboard)  shows an example of your existing leader board. You should be able to extract your user from json.

Answer (score 1):

From here:

> https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/realtime.html

You can see a typical JSON file for a user, in which you find:

> ```
>     "stats": {
>         "checkinsCount": 7313,
>         "usersCount": 565,
>         "tipCount": 128
>     },
> ```

You can parse this however you like.